# DatePicker arrow issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've added DatePicker on the page , but I've got smth like this , why is it can occurs ? Should I add some tag in index.html , or what should I do ?

[image: calendar]

```
import 'date-fns'
import React from 'react'
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns'
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider, DatePicker } from 'material-ui-pickers'

function DatePickerField (
  {
    input,
    className,
    selectedDate,
    input: { name, onChange, value },
    label,
    meta: { touched, error },
    required,
    ...restProps
  }
) {
  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider
      utils={DateFnsUtils}
      className={className}
      required={required}
      error={!!(touched && error)}
    >
      <DatePicker
        {...restProps}
        label={label}
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={(event, value) => input.onChange(event, value)}
        name={name}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  )
}

export default DatePickerField
```

Answer (score 0):

https://material-ui-pickers.firebaseapp.com/installation - here you can find response add this tag in the `index.html` file `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">`